# Is it possible to use Pytorch on AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, pytorch, data-science

I used **zappa** to upload my classifier project to AWS Lambda. After I imported the torch package in my program, the build failed. It fails only when I import **torch** or **torchvision** packages.
Is there a way to upload these packages?

Error:

> ```
> Waiting for stack website-aws-api-dev to update..
>
> 6res [00:06,  1.05s/res]
>
> Deploying API Gateway..
>
> Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.
> ```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have added the error message. Please get back to me.